# addMarkers requires non-NULL longitude/latitude values in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a Shiny Application which shows the Map, So I am using `Leaflet()` library for displaying the map. Below are my UI.R and Server.R

`UI.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = div(img(src="new.gif", height = 40, width = 
                   200),"My Dashboard",width = 300)),
   dashboardSidebar(
              sidebarMenu(
                   menuItem("Location", tabName = "Location")
                          )
                    )
   dashboardBody(
    tabItem("Map",
            fluidRow( 
              leafletOutput("mymap")
                    )
            )
```

`Server.R`

```
 library(shiny)
 library(leaflet)

 shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

   output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
                   leaflet() %>%
                  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
                  addMarkers(lng=df$Lon, 
                      lat=df$Lat)%>%
                  addPolylines(lng=df$Lon, 
                               lat=Lat)
                                })
    })
```

The values of `Lattitude` and `Longitude` is being retrieved from a dataframe `df`

```
  df <- data.frame("lat" = c(12.8908,12.891,12.890), 
                  "Lon" = c(77.5904,77.588,77.5868))
```

So when I run the above scripts it says `Error: addMarkers requires non-NULL longitude/latitude values.`

I am not able to trace down the error, I tried converting it to vector because `validateCoords()` require `lat` and `lon` to be in `vector` format but it did not help.

Comment: where is `df` created? Does it exist in the shiny application?

Comment: @SymbolixAU Oh my bad, `df` was not created inside the shiny application. I had created it in my local environment. But here is my doubt, When I try to implement the same logic of rendering map in `Shiny Application` it did work but when I try to run it in `Shiny Dashboard` is showing the error.

Comment: Can you edit your question showing a complete app causing the error (make it minimal, so it just includes the leaflet map and `df` data.)

Answer (score 1):

In your dataframe df the columns are called "lat" and "Lon" however in addMarkers() you try to use the columns "Lat" and "Lon". So you spelled lat differently (Lat vs lat).
Does this solve your problem?

In addition to that, in addPolylines() you specify lat=Lat. If you would like to use the column from the dataframe df again it should be lat=df$lat