# Error: addCircleMarkers requires non-NULL longitude/latitude values in shiny r?

Tags: r, shiny

starting with shiny apps for sort of first time and getting stuck in this issue:

> Error: addCircleMarkers requires non-NULL longitude/latitude values

Where am i suppose to put the data to not get this error?

I have also checked other SO post like: [addMarkers requires non-NULL longitude/latitude values in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833155/addmarkers-requires-non-null-longitude-latitude-values-in-r-shiny)

But still not sure what exactly is wrong here.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
# library(htmlwidgets)
# library(htmltools)
library(readxl)
library(RCurl)

URL <- "https://www.mohfw.gov.in/pdf/PMJAYPRIVATEHOSPITALSCONSOLIDATED.xlsx"
download.file(URL, destfile = "../../timesnow_PMJAYPRIVATEHOSPITALSCONSOLIDATED.xlsx",method = "curl")

# Data
ind_vaccination_leaflet <- readxl::read_xlsx(path = "../../timesnow_PMJAYPRIVATEHOSPITALSCONSOLIDATED.xlsx",
                                             sheet = 1)

ind_vaccination_leaflet <- ind_vaccination_leaflet %>% 
    mutate(label_display = paste(
        "<h2>", "Center: ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$`Name of the Vaccination Site*`, "</h2>",
        "<h3>",ind_vaccination_leaflet$`District*`, ", ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$`State*`, "</h3>",
        "<p>", "Address: ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$Address, "</p>",
        "<p>", "Pincode: ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$`PinCode*`, "</p>",
        "<p>", "Mobile: ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$`Mobile Number`, "</p>",
        "<p>", "Contact Person: ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$`Contact Person`, "</p>"
    )
    )


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Covid19 Vaccination Centers in India"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(h3("List of Vaccination Centers is plotted on Map & also listed in searchable table."),
                     
                     "source of list:",
                     a("https://www.timesnownews.com/india/article/covid-19-vaccination-in-uttar-pradesh-check-complete-list-of-govt-and-private-hospitals-for-jab/726412"),
                     br(),
                     br(),

                     a("https://www.oneindia.com/india/full-list-of-private-hospitals-where-the-covid-19-vaccine-will-be-administered-3223706.html"),
                     br(),
                     br(),
                     "P.S - There might be more center additions to this light, kindly recheck from other sources as well"),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("map")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        
        # Creating map object & adding layers
        leaflet() %>%
            setView(lat = 26.64510, lng = 80.17012, zoom = 5) %>%
            addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter, group = "Dark") %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron, group = "Light") %>%
            addProviderTiles("Stamen.Terrain", group = "Terrain") %>%
            addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "WorldImagery") %>%
            addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM","WorldImagery","Dark","Light","Terrain")) %>%
            addCircleMarkers(
                lng = ind_vaccination_leaflet$lon,
                lat = ind_vaccination_leaflet$lat,
                label = lapply(ind_vaccination_leaflet$label_display, htmltools::HTML),
                color = "midnightblue",
                weight = 1,
                radius = 8
            )%>%
            addMiniMap(tiles = providers$OpenStreetMap, width = 120, height=80)
        
    })
}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column names are called `Longitude*` and `Latitude*` and in `ui` you have to use `leafletOutput` instead of `plotOutput`.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Covid19 Vaccination Centers in India"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(h3("List of Vaccination Centers is plotted on Map & also listed in searchable table."),
                 
                 "source of list:",
                 a("https://www.timesnownews.com/india/article/covid-19-vaccination-in-uttar-pradesh-check-complete-list-of-govt-and-private-hospitals-for-jab/726412"),
                 br(),
                 br(),
                 
                 a("https://www.oneindia.com/india/full-list-of-private-hospitals-where-the-covid-19-vaccine-will-be-administered-3223706.html"),
                 br(),
                 br(),
                 "P.S - There might be more center additions to this light, kindly recheck from other sources as well"),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("map")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    
    # Creating map object & adding layers
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(lat = 26.64510, lng = 80.17012, zoom = 5) %>%
      addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter, group = "Dark") %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron, group = "Light") %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.Terrain", group = "Terrain") %>%
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "WorldImagery") %>%
      addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM","WorldImagery","Dark","Light","Terrain")) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        lng = ind_vaccination_leaflet$`Longitude*`,
        lat = ind_vaccination_leaflet$`Latitude*`,
        label = lapply(ind_vaccination_leaflet$label_display, htmltools::HTML),
        color = "midnightblue",
        weight = 1,
        radius = 8
      )%>%
      addMiniMap(tiles = providers$OpenStreetMap, width = 120, height=80)
    
  })
}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ronak .. for helping out again !!!. Appreciate your continuous support :)